# How to find files on Linux where only root has read permission

Tags: linux, shell, find, root, file-permissions

I want to find files in some folder like  `/home/mike/www/test` where only root has read permissions and not any other user.

EDIT: I have the `sudo` and permission but I want to list all files where only root has read permission but not any group or public?

Comment: Can you `sudo` to get root permissions?

Comment: i have sudo and root permissions

Comment: If a file has 0 permissions (or other weird settings like 333), then the owner cannot at the moment read those files (though the owner could change the permission so that they could read those files). Also, if a directory on the path leading to the file is not accessible (the x-bit) to the general world (e.g. the directory is owned by root with 700 permission), then ordinary files under that directory are not readable by others, regardless of who owns them or the permissions on the file. So, there are other possible interpretations for the question, but the selected answer is most plausible.

Comment: how can i get those files who have special permissions

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
find /home/mike/www/test -user root -perm +400 ! -perm +044 -print
```

`-perm +400` matches files that have at least the owner-read mode set. `-perm +044` matches files that have either group-read or other-read modes set, but `!` inverts the test so these files are excluded from the result.

UPDATE:
The man page for find(GNU findutils) says:

> -perm +mode This is no longer supported (and has been deprecated since 2005).  Use -perm /mode instead."

The updated command should be:

```
find /home/mike/www/test -user root -perm /400 ! -perm /044 -print
```

Comment: Says `find: invalid mode ‘+400’`

Comment: @VijayChavda I can't reproduce that error. What version of `find` are you using?

Comment: find (GNU findutils) 4.7.0-git

Comment: I had no error with `find 4.4.2` on Debian or BSD `find` on OS X. I don't know why you got that error. This syntax has been supported in `find` for decades.

Comment: Even I'm not sure, but thanks for the help anyways.

Comment: Do you get that error if you use `-perm 400`? This won't give the correct answer, it's just a test.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `find` command to determine just which directories and files *are* only readable by root.  Something like this might do what you want:

```
sudo find / -uid 0 -perm 600
```

This will generate a list of all files owned by UID 0 (root) with only read permissions for root.  The list will be absolute pathnames.

You can redirect the output to a file, or pipe it to another program.

Do `man find` for a comprehensive list of options supported.

Comment: `-perm 600` matches files with read and write, but not execute, permissions for the owner. It also excludes files where the group and other have write or execute permissions.

Answer (score -1):

Try using the `sudo` command to elevate your permissions.

```
sudo ls /home/mike/www/test
```

or

```
sudo find /home/mike/www/test -name "foo" -print
```

If you cannot do that you will need to have a system administrator add your login to the `/etc/sudoers` file.

Comment: i think u didn't understood my questions. I want to list all files in folders and under subfolders where only root has read permission but not any other user or group

Comment: Ah, yes, I did misunderstand the question.

Comment: Why has this answer been kept, since it's based on a misreading of the question?